# How to make html view/template that updates with new data from changed file

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I have a basic function called "follow" that monitors for file changes. That function yields each new line that is added to that file. That part works well, at least from what I see when testing it with print function.
Now, I want to display those new lines as table rows in HTML template.

This is my app main function:

```
import time
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


def follow(myfile):
    myfile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        new_line = myfile.readline()
        if not new_line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield new_line


logfile = open("/files/myfile.log")
new_lines = follow(logfile)
raw_list = []


@app.route("/home")
def output_log():
    for new_line in new_lines:
        print(new_line)
        raw_list.append(new_line)
        result_list = json.dumps(raw_list)
        print(new_line)
        # return render_template("systemlog.html", results=result_list, mimetype='text/html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

I am using jinja templating and I managed to display data in table from static file, but how to do it when file has been constantly updated. Note that this will be "real time" monitoring.

As you can see, I've tried some desperate moves, including rendering file with each iteration inside for loop, from which I did not expected any stable results. Also I've seen that people use ajax for rendering dynamic content, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it when monitoring file this way.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: I've never used them so not going to mark this as an answer as it might be wrong but sockets might be worth looking into. [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The reason your view isn't updating is when you hit the endpoint /home in your browser it runs the method `output_log` once and calls `render_template`. That method handles the conversion to html/what to send to your browser along with subbing values into Jinja templates. That only happens once. Your browser would have to initiate another request to get an update. That's why we use AJAX and sockets.

Comment: SocketIO is interesting, indeed. Definitely will be useful for other tasks, regardless if not here. I will look more into it.

Comment: Thank you for explanation for how method handle conversion to html, it is a good clue. Is there a way to use ajax in this situation? I am not running away from ajax or js in general, just stuck in situation with how to handle data generated this way..

Comment: The simple way I'd do it is to separate the front end and back end. Your flask app has an endpoint that instead of rendering a template, returns data in the form of JSON. Your front end app can use AJAX to make an HTTP call to that endpoint to get the data and then update itself independently. Then you can set up your front end webpage with javascript to make the request every minute or every 10 seconds and then you get a "live" dashboard without refreshing. Though based on my limited understanding of websockets if you want truly realtime updates then they'd be better as they work with events.

Comment: Have a look at REST APIs for inspiration. Here's a simple one I wrote using a few different libraries but the flask endpoint stuff is very simple and returns a string of json data depending on the request. [Github](https://github.com/tim-thompson/bonsai-trees)

Comment: Actually, that was helpful. I got an idea on how to try. Thanks dude, will notify you on results