# Html template that dynamically updates with new data from changed file

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

[How to make html view/template that updates with new data from changed file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51109250)

I am developing a chat messenger service and am storing messages in a SQL database i have made a similar file checking function like above question.
Is there anyway to add the output of this function into the html every time a new change to the database is detected?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't gone in to much detail on what you're using to do this, but I'm going to answer and assume you're working with `SocketIO`.

> Is there anyway to add the output of this function into the html every time a new change to the database is detected?

This is probaby the wrong way to think about this.  The question you linked deals with tailing a file, and then acting appropriately.  You shouldn't need to detect a database change, since your event function should be handling all the messages.

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/0c0a99a85f9528e1d66361d95ae0665f) of a very basic chat app which includes the functionality you desicribe. (Based on a tutorial which is linked in the README).

You should have a function which handles an incoming message from a user, then emits it on the socket, so other users on the system will see that message.  This is where you want to update your database:

```
@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    """ handle an incoming chat message, add to db, then emit to room """

    # Unique ID for the session
    json['sid'] = request.sid

    print('received my event: ' + str(json)) # Just prints to server terminal

    # Build the database entry and commit
    new_db_entry = ChatHistory(sid = json['sid'],
                               message = json['message'],
                               username= json['user_name'])
    db_session.add(new_db_entry)
    db_session.commit()

    # Escape nasty html.  Do this for each var the user enters
    json['user_name'] = su.escape(json['user_name'])
    json['message'] = su.escape(json['message'])

    socketio.emit('my response', json, callback=messageReceived)
```

You then have some corresponding Javascript which recieves this event in the frontend, and updates the HTML:

```
socket.on( 'my response', function( msg ) {
        if( typeof msg.user_name !== 'undefined' ) {
          $( 'div.message_holder' ).append( '<div><b style="color: #000">'+msg.user_name+'</b> '+msg.message+'</div>' )
        }
      })
```

However how do you render the history in a user's browser when they first connect?  You could write some Javascript to do this, however my example simply queries the database when a user first renders the `session.html` template (the frontend):

```
@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    history = ChatHistory.query.all()
    return render_template('session.html', history=history)
```

And then in the corresponding template, builds the page at load time:

```
   <div class="message_holder">
      {% for chatItem in history %}
          <div><b style="color: #000">{{ chatItem.username }}</b> {{ chatItem.message }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

This is just a sample of what can be done.